# Backbutton PHONEGAP

Tags: cordova

Staff helps me in this here... I am looking to the backbutton function, but already tried some form and all make the application exit. In emulate was already working. I do following:

```
function onLoad() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReadyBack, false);
}

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReadyBack() {
    // Register the event listener
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

// Handle the back button
//
function onBackKeyDown() {
    window.history.back();
    //alert("entro aqui");
}
```

How do not exit the application ?

Comment: You are testing on which platform ? In UWP, you have to listen a MS event.

Comment: I am testing in android, but must in ios. As I would be ?

Answer (score 1):

You should call `e.preventDefault()` in the `backbutton` event, like that :

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false );
}
```

Comment: I will test, but this will bring back in history, as in the example of what I do ?

Comment: This will simply cancel the back navigation. If you want to be able to cancel the back navigation only if it will exit your app and not if it do a back navigation inside your app, you have to register if there is a back navigation possible (HTML 5 API for navigation does not allow to easily check the history).

Comment: It is giving an error in this your code, nor start he wanted, would have as concerted it.

Comment: A very strange behavior happens. When testo emulator he apparently works, but when testo in cellular itself does not work, he closes the application.